# How can I improve Tesseract results quality?

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

I'm trying to read the NIRPP number (social security number) from a French vital card using Tesseract's OCR (I'm using `TesseractOCRiOS` 4.0.0). So here is what I'm doing :

First, I request a picture of the whole card :

[image]

Then, using a custom cropper, I ask the user to zoom specifically on the card number:

[image]

And then I catch this image (**1291**x**202**px) and using Tesseract I try to read the number:

```
let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng")
tesseract?.image = pickedImage
tesseract?.recognize()
print("\(tesseract?.recognizedText ?? "")")
```

But I'm getting pretty bad results... only like 30% of the time Tesseract is able to find the right number, and among these sometimes I need to trim some characters (like alpha characters, dots, dashes...).

So is there a solution for me to improve these results?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**To improve your results :**

- Zoom  your image to appropriate level. Right amount of  zoom will improve your accuracy by a lot.
- Configure tesseract so that only digits are whitelisted . I am
  assuming here what you are  trying to extract contains only digits.If
  you whitelist only digits    then it will improve your chances of
  recognizing 0 as 0 and not O    character.
- If your extracted text matches a regex, you should    configure
  tesseract to use that regex as well.
- Pre process your  image to remove any background colors and apply
  Morphology effects  like erode to increase the space between your
  characters/digits. If    they are too close , tesseract will have
  hard time recognizing them    correctly. Most of the image processing
  library comes prebuilt with    those effects.
- Use tiff as image format.

Once you have the right preprocessing pipeline and configuration for tesseract , you will usually get a very good and consistent result.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you need to do it....

1.you need to apply black and white or gray scale on image.
you will use default functionality like Graphics framework or third party libray like openCV or GPUImage for applying black&white or grayscale.

2.and then apply text detection using Vision framework.
From vision text detection you can crop texts according to vision text detected coordinates.
3.pass this cropped images(text detected) to TesseractOCRiOS...

I hope it will work for your use-case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I discovered that Tesseract recognizes a text only if the given image contain a region of interest.
I solved the problem using [Apple' Vision framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision). It has `VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest` that returns `CGRect` of detected text according to the image. Then you can crop the image to region where text is present and send them to Tesseract for detection.

[Ray Smith](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/33418.pdf) says:

> Since HP had independently-developed page layout analysis  technology  that  was  used  in  products,  (and therefore not released for open-source) Tesseract never needed   its   own   page   layout   analysis.   Tesseract therefore  assumes  that  its  input  is  a  binary  image  with   optional polygonal text regions defined.

[image: Vision-Tesserat]